# div row doesn't align all buttons correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-bee-space-blue dropdown-toggle buttonWidth" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Generate Report <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: { data: ReportExportTypes, as: 'exportType' }">
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-bind="reportExportTypeText: exportType, click: $root.OnGenerateReportClick.bind($root, exportType)"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-bee-grey buttonWidth pull-right BackToScorecard" data-bind="click: $root.BackToScorecard, tooltip: { title: 'Back to Scorecard' }">Back to Scorecard</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which shows up correctly like this:

[image: first piece of html rendered]

But when I add the following code:

```html
<div class="col-md-1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-bee-space-blue buttonWidth"  data-bind="click: EmailPopup, tooltip: { title: 'Get report to your email' },
    enable: ReportingEditEnabled"> Email Report</button>
</div>
```

It totally breaks all the alignment of my buttons, it shows up like this:

[image: broken alignment]

Here is the full code with the button in it:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-bee-space-blue dropdown-toggle buttonWidth" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Generate Report <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: { data: ReportExportTypes, as: 'exportType' }">
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="reportExportTypeText: exportType, click: $root.OnGenerateReportClick.bind($root, exportType)"></a></li>
      </ul>
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-bee-space-blue buttonWidth"  data-bind="click: EmailPopup, tooltip: { title: 'Get report to your email' }, 
            enable: ReportingEditEnabled"> Email Report</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-bee-grey buttonWidth pull-right BackToScorecard" data-bind="click: $root.BackToScorecard, tooltip: { title: 'Back to Scorecard' }">Back to Scorecard</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my *Generate Report*, *Email Report* and *Back to scorecard* buttons all in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the offset for the last button to 7. The idea is that since there are 12 columns in a row and you have `col-md-2` and `col-md-1` (the buttons on the left), you have 9 columns remaining to the end of the row. And if the last button is 2 columns wide, 7 columns remain between it and the other two as offset.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-bee-space-blue dropdown-toggle buttonWidth" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Generate Report <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: { data: ReportExportTypes, as: 'exportType' }">
        <li><a href="#"
            data-bind="reportExportTypeText: exportType, click: $root.OnGenerateReportClick.bind($root, exportType)"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-bee-space-blue buttonWidth" data-bind="click: EmailPopup, tooltip: { title: 'Get report to your email' }, 
      enable: ReportingEditEnabled"> Email Report</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-bee-grey buttonWidth pull-right BackToScorecard" data-bind="click: $root.BackToScorecard, tooltip: { title: 'Back to Scorecard' }">Back to Scorecard</button>
  </div>
</div>
```